# What is the correct syntax of SRV data in Google Cloud DNS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

Can anyone please tell me the correct syntax of SRV data in Google Cloud DNS dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

Full name on domain like:

```
_sipinternaltls._tcp."domain name that is fixed"
```

Example:

```
_sipinternaltls._tcp.domain.com
```

Resource Record : SRV 
TTL : As shown on guide of installation
TTL Unit : choose s,m,h,d,w
SRV Data : Priority Weight Port SIP

Example:

```
0 0 5061 sip.domain.com.
```

must finish with `.`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of SRV data should be priority weight port target, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record. An example could be "10 20 5060 foo.bar." (Quotes are only used to call attention to the SRV data).

Comment: An example of the SRV record on Cloud DNS [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/what-is-cloud-dns)